# Authorise user for action in microservice

Tags: c#, .net-core, oauth-2.0, microservices

Something i have been searching the interwebs on, but not found proper answers.

We are redoing a big legacy system into Micro services, and i am bumping my head into authorization (who is allowed to do what).

We have a backoffice for our different brands in a multi tenant setup. Then we have a brand service and a product service. Users can add products etc. to their brand.
We use ping federate for authentication .
(Admin users have a role which enables them to work on all brands - this is located in the id_token)

Question is: How should i authorize the user to be a part of a Brand in terms of seeing or creating things on the brand, such as a new product. They live in different microservices.

Option 1: I could verify the user when a call comes from client (server side blazor) -> product service (create product) then -> Check if user is allowed to do action in Brand Service,

Option 2: Have the create of a product to go through brand service, verify it, then down to product.
But these two  a bit chatty?

Option 3: Let Product service have a notion of who is allowed to do what from brand services. (event driven)

Option 4: Somehow add a notion of brand to the ping federate AD? Though we do onto control that instance, so it would create a big dependency on that other group.

I'd like to keep the domain knowledge close in the services.

Answer (score 0):

In case of authentication service as microservice, you should to create one. With its own user/rights database.
You should [check this article](https://dev.koshovyi.com/2020/10/22/bitovye-maski-i-flagi-v-net-c/), (translate it if you need), its very helpful on base tech level for understanding.

So, in your case, first of all, user authenticate with Auth service and gets JWT token or Cert. And with every call to other services user attach this "token". So, other services can check user auth/privileges/rights with Auth service.